# Deserialize json two-dimensional array to list of objects

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a problem with deserializing json:

```
{
"rows": [
        [
          4,
          4,
          5
        ],
        [
          3,
          3,
          3
        ],
        [
          6,
          7,
          7
        ]
      ]
}
```

My model looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Builder(builderClassName = "AttemptBuilder", toBuilder = true)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Attempt.AttemptBuilder.class)
class Action{
    List<Attempt> attempts;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class ActionBuilder {
    }
}

@Builder(builderClassName = "Attempt Builder", toBuilder = true)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Attempt .Attempt Builder.class)
class Attempt {
    List<Integer> attemptList;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class AttemptBuilder {
    }
}
```

I am having error:

```
JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize instance of `Attempt$AttemptBuilder` out of START_ARRAY
```

When I replace
`List<Attempt> attempts`
with
`List<List<Integer>> attempts`
everything is working fine, but I would like to have List of custom objects.
Does anyone has idea how to fix it?

Comment: Should be able to just extend your Attempt class to ArrayList<Integer> `Attempt extends ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: I think this could be something todo with @Builder annotation. Try using @ AllArgsConstructor 
@ NoArgsConstructor annotations. It should help to create the entites.

Comment: Builder is working fine. The problem is that nested arrays has no property name.